# database design for generalized settings in to single table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have several settings for single project, i wants to map all settings into single table,

```
 For Example:(1)Currency Changer setting: Fields: (toCurrency,fromCurrency,price,statusType)

             (2) scheduler settings: Fields: (startdate,enddate,task)
```

If i create a single table with all fields, then if i entered the scheduler setting the other settings remains empty and visa versa.

i have problem to wrap all fields into single settings table,

Can anyone tell me how to create generalized single table or which is best way to wrap both setting in single application table.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with multiple tables? If not, you are probably best-off just keeping them. Sure, you could do a form of EAV as [gbejic proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836057/533120), but that has problems of its own, especially if you need to reference settings from other tables (via foreign keys) or if settings are of varying types (as seems to be the case based on your example).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this in two tables.

One is `setting_types(id, name)` and other is `settings (id, setting_type_id, value)`

But if you still want to do in one table you can use next table

```
settings(id, setting_name (enum of settings), value)
```

This one table option has limit of adding new settings.